# How to open a very big whole slide image given as .tif image file using Java?

Tags: java, tiff

I have some image files in .tif format, all of them are very big ~3.1 - 3.5 GB!

As I know all of this tif files have pyramid structure of 10 images inside. So, each image inside of a .tif has 10 different resolution. We call it Whole Slide Image, this kind of images are used is histopathological cases (scans of tissues with cancer).

I tried to write a Java Application based on SWING, JavaFX, Eclipse SWT, TwelveMonkeys Library, all of them worked with a standard, simple .tif file from google. But none worked with my big .tif files. I also found two Applications on GitHub, one was built with Java Swing and the other one with JavaFX both has OpenSlide Java bindings as underlaying part. As I see the integration of this was very complex so I want avoid to use in C written OpenSlide Java bindings (as I know there are not stable too).

Im searching for an easy way to open and display my files. Any suggestions?

One of this files you can download here: 
ftp://parrot.genomics.cn/gigadb/pub/10.5524/100001_101000/100439/CAMELYON16/training/normal/normal_001.tif

Comment: Converting this big image to JPEG format first is ok for you?  What you cares about most when showing?

Comment: We use this images as input for our neural networks, any compression can erase important data. So I cant convert it.

Comment: If so, you shouldn't display it. For display, you only need a tiny version.

Comment: If there are 10 different resolutions, which resolution do you wish to display?  The largest one?  And when you say “none worked with my big .tif files,” what do you mean?  Did you get an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: It looks like your image is a BigTIFF, which doesn’t have much support in most image reading libraries.  You may have luck with the [Bio-Formats](https://openmicroscopy.org/info/bio-formats) library, which claims to be capable of reading BigTIFF files.

Comment: Hi, author of the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO library here. :-) We support BigTIFF, and the TIFF plugin does *read* your TIFF file. The problem is that the images it contains are way too big to be represented as normal `BufferedImage`s (the "pyramid" is stored largest to smallest, the 3 first images are too big). The remaining 7 displays just fine.

Comment: PS: About compression, the image data in your BigTIFF file all uses `Compression: 7`, which means they are already JPEG compressed... It should be possible to rip them out to normal JPEG files, with no further quality loss if that helps. But I suggest reading the file as-is, and instead read in smaller regions and feed to your neural network.

Comment: @haraldK thank you. Can you explain how to find biggest possible region? And is this a not enough  RAM issue? Can I open level with more RAM ?

Comment: @Tristate Iit’s just w * h * bitsPerPixel / 8. This must be less than Integer.MAX_VALUE (roughly 2 GB). It does not matter if you have more memory, because Java uses signed ints for array addressing. It’s possible read larger images, but that requires some kind of tiling. Your TIFF is already tiled, so I suggest reading and processing one tile at a time. Will be faster and use less memory than reading all up front.